# NodeJS: How to send a Buffer in chunks

Tags: node.js, express, streaming

I'm trying to create an artificially slow-loading image with NodeJS (currently using ExpressJS). I have Buffer containing a base64-encoded image in it, and I'd like to stream chunks of the buffer to the client each separated by a given delay. Is this possible?

I know how to send raw text to the client in chunks, and I know how to send an entire Buffer to the client (both of these with `response.write()`), but I am not sure how I can break up an image's bytes into chunks and send that to the client incrementally. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct slices from a buffer using [`buf.subarray(start, end)`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/buffer.html#bufsubarraystart-end) and send these via `response.write`.

Comment: buf.slice() is now depreciated, use buf.subarray() https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/buffer.html#bufsubarraystart-end